# how to access with single shared_ptr to vector of shared_ptr element

Tags: c++, vector, overriding, virtual, shared-ptr

i need to call the overidden function inside `B` class through `C` class but it gives `"Base"` as a output rather than `"Derived"`. when I call this code part `classC.getTargetB().example();` i need to get `"Derived"` as a output. how can i reach my goal in the code.

```
class A {

public:
    A() {};
    virtual void example() { std::cout << "Base" << std::endl; }
};
```

```
class B :public A {

protected:
    std::string name;

public:
    B() {};
    B(std::string n) { name = n; }
    void example() override { std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl; }
};
```

```
class C {
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> ptr;

    std::shared_ptr<A> targetBobject;

public:
    void setB(std::shared_ptr<A> target) {
        targetBobject = target;
    }
    A getTargetB() {
        return *targetBobject;
    }
};
```

```
int main()
{
    A example;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> parent;

    C classC;

    std::shared_ptr<B> ptr1 = std::make_shared<B>("B1");
    std::shared_ptr<B> ptr2 = std::make_shared<B>("B2");

    parent.push_back(std::move(ptr1));
    parent.push_back(std::move(ptr2));


    //parent.at(0)->example(); this gives 'Derived' as a output

    classC.setB(parent.at(0));
    classC.getTargetB().example();// gives 'Base' as a output
}
```

Comment: `A getTargetB()` This does object slicing. You need to return a pointer or a reference.

Comment: i tried to return pointer but it gives a error like that "no suitable user-defined conversion from to exists"

Comment: `A* getTargetB() { return targetBobject.get(); }` or `A& getTargetB() { return *targetBobject; }`